# Core Data one-to-many relationship not being persisted to store through Magical Record

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm attempting to store data I receive from a couple web APIs in Core Data. The data comes in correctly, and I parse the JSON correctly. Two of my entities are causing the following problem:

```
@interface Instance : NSManagedObject
... snipped properties ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* details;
@end

@interface Instance (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
-(void)addDetailsObject:(Detail*)value;
-(void)addDetails:(NSSet*)values;
-(void)removeDetailsObject:(Detail*)value;
-(void)removeDetails:(NSSet*)value;
@end

@interface Details : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* detailId;
... snipped properties ...
@end
```

I download the Details from an API first, and then I download the instances from a separate API. I then parse the JSON array of DetailIds and use

```
BOOL success = [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext* localContext) {
    for (NSString* parsedDetailId in parsedDetailsIds) 
    {
        Detail* detail = [Detail MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"detailId" withValue:parsedDetailId inContext:localContext];
        if (detail)
        {
            [instance.addDetailsObject:detail];
        }
    }
}];
```

to store the newly created links. There are only a couple details per instance. When these details are downloaded, everything works as expected in the local context and the default context. However, if I close the app and load from the persistent store, or if I use the debugger to reset the context, some of the details links will disappear. Some Instances with 2 details will have 1 or 0, most will behave correctly.

Its always the same Instance->Details links that are not persisted, but I can't see any obvious link between the ones that are missing. There are no errors in Core Data or MagicalRecord. The saves all return success.

Has anyone had any issues similar to this? What did you do? What are some things I can try?

This is a many-to-many link, but I didn't model Details back to Instances because I don't need that traversal. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the localContext in your findFirst call. The changes you're performing are in a background queue with a new, local context. The saveWithBlock method is then only saving the localContext, not the defaultContext. The defaultContext is the one that is used when you don't specify one, as you are doing in your sample code.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. This is a transcription error on my part. Mismatched contexts will actually throw an error. I have updated the code with the local context.